# What is the most time efficient way to tell if a key is in a c++ unordered_map?

Tags: c++

Right now if the unordered_map we say is "mp", my way to tell if one key is in that unordered_map is:

```
mp.find(key) != mp.end()
```

But it looks like that we have to traverse all keys in mp. Is this right?

And if there is a better way to check if a key is in a unordered_map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, an `std::unordered_map` is a hash table, and [`std::unordered_map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) is constant time on average. You don't have to traverse all the keys. There may be some sequential look-up inside a bucket in the case of hash collisions.

Note that you can also use the [`count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/count) member, which saves you one comparison:

```
bool b = mp.count(key);
```

Whether this is more "efficient" should be determined with profiling.

---

> **C++11 §23.2.5/10 table 103** (from N3290):
>   `b.find(k)` … Average case O(1), worst case O(b.size()).

Comment: Are any of the implementations worse than constant time? If so is there a good reason they are?

Comment: @sjdowling It all depends on the hash function and the elements put in the map, so all implementations *can* be worse than constant time in some cases. Imagine a hash function that returns 42 always. All the elements end up in the same bucket, so look-up is O(N) where N is the number of elements in the map.

Comment: @sjdowling: the standard has complexity guarantees, which means that any piece of code with the same call interface but with non-constant amortized time, isn't an implementation of the standard. assuming a hash function that's OK, such as the ones for built-in types.

Comment: Oops. I thought it is multimap.